# Get error when I try to make AJAX POST call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I create View in action page:

```
       public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

            return View();
        }
}
```

At some point in the View I make POST call to **another controller** using AJAX:

```
function Save() {
    if (sensorData) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/../Sensor/SaveData',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("No Data.");
    }
}
```

This is code of the API controller:

```
    public class SensorController : ApiController
    {
        public IHttpActionResult SaveData()
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest("Data not saved");
            }
        }
}
```

But I get this error:
**"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:7486/Sensor/SaveData"**

Any idea why I get the error?And how to solve the problem.

Comment: how do you map the routes?

Comment: Try using `url: "@Url.Action("SaveData", "Senso")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to call an API Controller with an MVC route.
If you check your `WebApiConfig` you have probably just got the `DefaultApi` route defined:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

If that is the case change your Controller Action to add the `[HttpPost]` attribute

```
public class SensorController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveData()
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest("Data not saved");
        }
    }
}
```

Then make your Ajax call:

```
function Save() {
    if (sensorData) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Sensor',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("No Data.");
    }
}
```

Note: you don't appear at this point to be posting any data to the server.